# setInterval function causing console to log something multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which uses setInterval to increase an image size and make a close button appear. Once I click the close button the the image decreases in size again. I also have some classes being added/removed etc but it only works once and if I decrease the size again the formatting starts messing up so in an attempt to debug I added console.log('test') and noticed that it get's logged an additional time each time i close an image.

For example, I click close the first time and it get's logged once correctly. Next time I close an image it's been called 3 times in total, next time it' called 6 times in total.

Surely, the console should only log it once, when the height decreases to 200.

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');


  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.addEventListener('click', enlarge);
  });

  function enlarge(e) {
    var image = e.target,
      interval,
      height = 200,
      width = 200,
      z = $(this).css("z-index"); //Obtain the current z-index of the image which has been clicked
    /*thisProduct = */

    $(this).css("z-index", z + 10); //increase the z-index of just the image which has been selected by 10

    $('#product-container').addClass('disable-click'); //Stops other products from being enlarged whilst another is
    $('.unhidden').not($(this).closest('.unhidden')).addClass('hide');
    $(this).parent().parent().css("float", "left");
    //$('.unhidden').not($(this)).addClass('noOpacity');
    //$('.unhidden').addClass("hide");


    $("#close-button").click(function() {
      $("#close-button").css("visibility", "hidden");
      $("#dimmed-cover").css("visibility", "hidden");


      interval = setInterval(function() {
        height -= 6.666; //Need to decrease by 400px so 400/60 = 6.666
        width -= 6.666;

        if (height <= 200 && width <= 200) { //Once is beyond the desired size, set the final dimensions
          height = 200;
          width = 200;

        }

        if (height === 200 && width === 200) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          console.log("test")
          $('.unhidden').removeClass('hide');
          $('.unhidden').css("float", "none");
        }

        image.style.height = height + 'px';
        image.style.width = width + 'px';
      }, 8.334);


    });

    interval = setInterval(function() {
      height += 6.666; //Need to enlarge by 400px so 400/60 = 6.666
      width += 6.666;

      if (height >= 600 && width >= 600) { //Once is beyond the desired size, set the final dimensions
        height = 600;
        width = 600;
        clearInterval(interval);
        $("#close-button").css("visibility", "visible"); //Making these visible AFTER the image has enlarged to prevent a bug happening if the user clicks close
        $("#dimmed-cover").css("visibility", "visible"); //before the image has finished enlarging
      }

      image.style.height = height + 'px';
      image.style.width = width + 'px';
    }, 8.334); //1000/60 = 16.667 fps

  }

  $("#close-button").click(function() {
    $('#product-container').removeClass('disable-click'); //Enable other products to be clicked again
    $('.thumbnail').css("z-index", 1200); //Resets the z-index of all images to the same value to prevent a thumbnail being over the top of an enlarged image
  });

});
```

```css
    #product-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    
    .product-wrapper {
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #product {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 252px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: solid 2px black;
    }
    
    .image-container {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .product-text {
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 50px;
        border-top: solid 2px black;
        background: #009641; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #009641 0%, #a1d54f 96%, #80c217 100%, #7cbc0a 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #009641 0%,#a1d54f 96%,#80c217 100%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #009641 0%,#a1d54f 96%,#80c217 100%,#7cbc0a 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    }
    
    .thumbnail {
        position: relative;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 1200;
    }
    
    .unhidden {
        
    }

#dimmed-cover { /* dims the background apart from the header and the form*/
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1100;
}

#close-button { /* button to close the hidden-window */
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    right: 0;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1200;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
    background: #009641;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dimmed-cover"></div>
<div id="close-button">Close.</div>

<div id="product-container">
                            <div class="product-wrapper">
                                <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                    <img src="assets/home-bg.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="product-text">
                                        TEST
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                    <img src="assets/enchilada.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="product-text">
                                        TEST
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                    <img src="assets/quesadilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="product-text">
                                        TEST
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                    <img src="assets/shrimp.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="product-text">
                                        TEST
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                    <img src="assets/tacos.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="product-text">
                                        TEST
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                                <div id="product" class="unhidden">
                                    <div class="image-container">
                                    <img src="assets/tortilla.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                                    </div>    
                                    <div class="product-text">
                                        TEST
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- Product container -->
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: @gyre Done, that should be everything relevent. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

*Interval's running when It's born to the moment when you kill your process or when u make decision to stop it.
You may stop it by using `clearInterval()`[(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) function which's part of webAPI.
There's simple example how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/1f4Lsp61/
I would like to, recommend you to get much more knowledge about Event Loop in JavaScript, there's link which helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ
@Edit:
In your case, u may make condition which may stop defined interval when some size cap's achieved.*

**@Edit2 [MAIN]:**
At line 26 of your code `$("#close-button").click(function()` you're adding event handlers each time you enlarging image. You have to detach'em by .off() operator. There's working example `$("#close-button").off().click(function()`.

Comment: I use clearInterval at the end of the function in the same part where I have the console.log

Comment: that's what i've done. Once the sie is below 200 it sets the height+width as 200, logs it in console and clears the interval

Comment: I saw some dependence on the amount of returning console.logs. Notice that amount of returning logs is increasing by 1 after every close pressing.  I 'm so curious what's reason of that harassment.

That seems to be some stacking of events etc.

Comment: ...also at the line `z = $(this).css("z-index");` you should transfer this var to become number `z = Number($(this).css("z-index")`. Your z-index was about 120010 after adding 10 by first click so It may cause some future problems.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I noticed it was increasing by 1 each time, makes no sense to me why it would be doing that. It should just be clearing the interval

Comment: Okay, I found solution. Your event listeners are stacking each click. Just make change at line 26. `$("#close-button").off().click(function() { ` it's detaching event handlers from element.

Comment: Unfortunatley that stops me from ebing able to click the images again to enlarge them though. When I added that line, I can enlarge an image once, close it to decrease it but then the images are no longer clickable

Comment: Hym, I don't know. I attaching jsfiddle which's working(?) in my case? Does it have same issue?

Comment: Thank you for your help, would you like me to give you a fiddle of my whole code so you could test it more easily etc?

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/cgvyvex0/ This fiddle actiually makes it easier to explain the problem, as you can see when i click the close button, it waits until it is small again before displaying the others and changing float, however the 2nd time i click the close button, it doesn't wait.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9gy794zf/, here we go buddy.

You had to use `event.preventDefault()` function, with it, we do not have to unbind anything.

Comment: Thank you, I still can't understand why the first time you click close, it waits until the image is small before displaying the others, btu the 2nd time it displays them as soon as you click close

Comment: There's thing which I would not like to use, you're hard-coded changes after clearInterval() call which is async.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? Is there somewhere else I could put them?

Comment: Never mind, I exaggerated with thinking. :D I hope I helped you, but I can't really find more issues.

Answer (score -1):

Does creating "interval" as global variable helps ?

i.e

var interval;
$(document).ready(function() {
...

Comment: Unfortunatley not, a few of the functions stop working entirely.